# Tokbox Video not working in iOS, Macbook

Tags: ios, macos, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

Recently implemented **Tokbox** in a project, I recognized there are some issues with iOS and OSX.

- Regarding iOS(iPad was used for testing), the **Tokbox** popped up with a message stating incompatibility.
- In OSX, the video comes for five seconds and disappears.

These are the following issues faced with **Tokbox**, well it worked well in Ubuntu, Windows. WebRTC is still not supported in iOS browser. Is there anything possible way to support WebRTC in iOS browsers? Did anyone face the similar problem as I faced with Macbook?

It is Macbook Air with OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.

Comment: It's working fine on macbook (mac os x el capitan here). As for iOS, it doesn't support webrtc yet (they started working on it this year). Don't expect it to work in Chrome on iOS either.

Comment: In iOS 11 the safari 11 browser will support WebRTC https://tokbox.com/developer/beta/safari/

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, there is no support for WebRTC on iOS browsers. If you want to use WebRTC on iOS you will need a native application.

Comment: Bowser claims to support WebRTC in iOS browsers, it doesn't work there too. Is there any easier to convert webapp to iOS app?

Comment: Based on this http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/, Safari does not support WebRTC at all. Regarding your question, there is no such an easy way IMO.

Comment: In iOS 11 the safari 11 browser will support WebRTC tokbox.com/developer/beta/safari